# How to get JSON value where key1=value1 and key2=value2

Tags: json, ruby

I'm trying to parse a complex JSON object with Ruby:

```
"data": [{
    "resourceId": 381,
    "resourceName": "Admin.Config",
    "resourceDesc": "Correspondence Admin -> Configuration",
    "permissions": [{
        "id": 1081,
        "operation": "Update",
        "assignedToRoleFlag": false
    }, {
        "id": 1071,
        "operation": "Read",
        "assignedToRoleFlag": false
    }],
    "productName": "Doc"
}, {
    "resourceId": 391,
    "resourceName": "Admin.Usage",
    "resourceDesc": "Correspondence Admin -> Usage",
    "permissions": [{
        "id": 1091,
        "operation": "Read",
        "assignedToRoleFlag": false
    }],
    "productName": "Doc"
}, ......................................     }
```

The issue is, I want to parse this to get `['data']['permissions']['id']` where `['data']['resourceName'] = Admin.Config` and `['data']['permissions']['operation'] = Read` for example.

I'm using this trying to get this value (perm = the JSON response above):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'json'

perm = response.body
file = perm
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data_you_want = data_hash["data"].detect do |h|
h["resourceName"] == "Admin.Config" and h["permissions"][0]["operation"] == "Read"
end
permid = data_you_want['permissions'][0]['id']
puts permid
```

Comment: Yes, so what's the problem here? After you `JSON.parse` it, it's just regular ruby hashes and arrays. Filter them however you like.

Comment: I edit the question and set the block of code that I'm using for this but it's not working for getting id based on 2 values.

Comment: define "not working". Please read the ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) and please stop adding nonsense. If you want to help COPY PASTE and run it

Comment: I would run it, but your code is not runnable. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's not about this code it's about getting a JSON value based on two parameters.

Comment: No, seriously, following instructions from these two links will greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer. Help people help you.

Comment: "COPY PASTE and run it", "It's not about this code" - make up your mind.

Comment: What didn't you understood from Get Json value where key1=value1 and key2=value2 ?

Comment: You see, this is isn't a "write code for me" kind of site, where you dump loose specifications and people rush to code it. If you're stuck, we will help. But you need to do your homework first.

Comment: In your case, `data_you_want['permissions']['id']` is wrong. `data_you_want['permissions']` returns an array. Array elements are accessed by numerical indexes. There's no element at index `"id"`. That is the source of your immediate problem. You would need to use something like `data_you_want['permissions'][0]['id']` to first get element of `permissions` collections and _then_ fetch its id. This, of course, is not enough to fulfill all the requirements you list in the question, but this might give you a nudge in the right direction. If you looked for nudge and not a complete job done, that is.

Comment: Ok now you are helpful, it works for the scenario above(just edit my question) but why it's not working if I change h["permissions"][0]["operation"] == "Update" `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) but if I set h["permissions"][1]["operation"] == "Update" it will return id permission from Read

Comment: Yep, of course. You need to iterate permissions too. Nested loop.

Comment: make sense. I Figure it out eventually. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution:

```
 guidz=[]
file = perm
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data_you_want = data_hash["data"].detect do |h|
puts h['permissions']
   if h["resourceName"] == "Admin.Config"
       h["permissions"].each do |permisiune|
           guidz << permisiune['id'] if permisiune['operation'] == 'Read'
           guidz << permisiune['id'] if permisiune['operation'] == 'Update'
      end
 end
    if h["resourceName"] == "Admin.Usage"
         h["permissions"].each do |permisiune|
           guidz << permisiune['id'] if permisiune['operation'] == 'Read'
        end
    end
end
puts guidz.inspect
```

Comment: See, wasn't that hard :)

Comment: btw, replace `.detect` with `.each` and drop `data_you_want` var. They're doing nothing. Actually `.detect` does less than nothing. It prevents your code from finding permissions for both `admin.config` and `admin.usage`. Worse of all, it only does that _sometimes_ (depends on order of data in your array) :)

Comment: :) yes the key was understanding [0] the key position. Done the changes and looks great. Thanks again.